# Not page after clone project Laravel from Git

Tags: php, laravel, github, laravel-artisan

1.git clone
2. install composer global and composer install in project
3. install node and install npm
3. .env file and key generate
4. npm run watch
5. php artisan serve

No mistake nowhere http://127.0.0.1:8000/games/ohdaihiep

Open  and get mistake
The requested resource /games/ohdaihiep was not found on this server.

Comment: all is okay without this??can you give your route file i mean web.php??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the steps listed, you haven't created a route that maps the `/games/ohdaihiep` route to any sort of controller.

Without a controller, there is nothing to generate a response and so the server is returning a 404 response indicating that the requested document wasn't found.

Comment: Sorry I forget say but him I write too.